# jUnit 4 DirectorySuiteBuilder Equivalent

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'd like to know if there is something similar to junit-addons DirectorySuiteBuilder ([documentation](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/util/DirectorySuiteBuilder.html)) that works with jUnit 4.  Simply stated, I want to load every file name *Test.java in a directory and build a suite out of them.

I realize that I can build a suite that runs every test in a directory using ant, but I would prefer to not go that route so that I can run the tests with eclipse's native jUnit plugin.

Comment: in IntelliJ you can just right-click on the folder containing the tests you want to Run... doesn't such thing exist in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough, al nik.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.